# twig: set variable with function

Tags: function, variables, twig

I want to set a variable with the content of a translation function:

```
{% set somevar = XXXXX %}
```

Within content, I call the translation like this, but I fail to put the function result into the var:

```
{% trans into _locale %}somefield{% endtrans %}
```

I tried many different aproaches, but I always failed, any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure as to what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to put the translation result INTO the `somevar`?

Comment: And can you add some examples for what `somevar` is used later on in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
{% set somevar = 'somefield' %}

{{ somevar|trans(_locale) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
{% set somevar %}
    {% trans into _locale %}somefield{% endtrans %} 
{% endset %}
```